# Cómo utilizar android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media

Tags: android, mediaqueries, gallery

Estoy creando una galería de fotos, el código q estoy utilizando me da acceso a todas las fotos del almacenamiento interno y externo, pero lo que quiero es mostrar en la galería solo las fotos que están dentro d una carpeta en específico, por ejemplo la carpeta Pictures q adentro tiene otras que serían los álbumes con las fotos

```
String album = null;
        String timestamp = null;
        Uri uriExternal = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Uri uriInternal = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED};

        Cursor cursorExternal = getContentResolver().query(uriExternal, projection, "bucket_display_name = \"" + album_name + "\"", null, null);
        Cursor cursorInternal = getContentResolver().query(uriInternal, projection, "bucket_display_name = \"" + album_name + "\"", null, null);
        Cursor cursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[]{cursorExternal, cursorInternal});
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
            album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME));
            timestamp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED));

            imageList.add(Function.mappingInbox(album, path, timestamp, Function.converToTime(timestamp), null));
        }
        cursor.close();
```

Quiero saber si hay alguna forma de pasarle esa URL al método de android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media. porque al leer la documentación no llegue a una conclusión d como hacerlo

Comment: "mostrar en la galería solo las fotos que están dentro d una carpeta en específico", que carpeta es la que deseas acceder?

Comment: La carpeta d la aplicación que estoy creando, que está en la memoria interna, lo que me interesa es saber cómo pasarle un path a ese método